# Why doesn't unsigned long long int in C++ allow negative values?

Tags: c++

I tried using the unsigned long long int type for implementing something similar to the BigInteger of Java in C++ but I found out that unfortunately unsigned long long int doesn't support negative values. Why doesn't C++ allow unsigned long long int to store negative values when it has such a huge range for positive values?

Comment: Because unsigned values are never negative?!? That's the exact meaning of the word? They behave just like cardinal numbers.

Comment: The keyword unsigned prevent a value from being negative.

Comment: And how come unsigned long long int doesn't support fractional values???

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types

Answer (score 2):

The keyword `unsigned` is a modifier for integer types and it means that the variable can't represent negative values. With this limitation it will however be able to store greater positive values than its `signed` counterpart. Which one you should choose depends on the situation.

Example:

- A *signed* 8 bit integer can (since C++20) hold values in the range `[-2^7, 2^7-1]` (`[-128, 127]`).
- An *unsigned* 8 bit integer can hold values in the range `[0, 2^8-1]` (`[0, 255]`).

[Signedness @ wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signedness)